# Flipping active = -1 to active = 1

Tags: php, mysql, database

Built this, and executed it, but the database in phpmyadmin has no changes... what am I missing?

Active is obviously a column name in each table... there are 107 tables I need to flip.

Thanks.

```
<?php

    mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "789feRNSHB")or die("cannot connect to server");
    mysql_select_db("core")or die("cannot select db");

    $sql = "SHOW TABLES FROM core";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);

    $arrayCount = 0;
    while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) {
        $tableNames[$arrayCount] = $row[0];
        $arrayCount++; //only do this to make sure it starts at index 0
    }

    //print_r($tableNames);

    for($i=0;$i<sizeof($tableNames);$i++){
        $table= $tableNames[$i];
        echo $query = "UPDATE ".$table." SET Active=1 where Active=-1";
        echo'>>'.mysql_query($query).'<br>';
    }

?>
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: No error is shown, it shows:

UPDATE activity SET Active=1 where Active=-1>>1
UPDATE activitytype SET Active=1 where Active=-1>>1
UPDATE addadjustment SET Active=1 where Active=-1>>
UPDATE addoptioin SET Active=1 where Active=-1>>
UPDATE address SET Active=1 where Active=-1>>1
UPDATE area SET Active=1 where Active=-1>>1


But when you refresh phpmyadmin they are still -1, I didnt copy paste all 107 tables showing UPDATE, just fyi. lol

Comment: What type of field is Active?

Comment: seems like it is RUNNING, but not saving a conversion?  Feel like im missing some small bit of code.

Comment: Try doing `select count(*) from activity where Active=-1` see what you get for the results.

Comment: Active is a Column within every table

Comment: But what is it's type... tinyint , integer, bigint, char, varchar etc.

Comment: and Active column is tinyint(1)

Comment: quote the 1 and -1 and see

Comment: quotes seem to have done it, knew it was something small i wasnt doing. haha, blonde moment, appreciate the second eyes both of you, give me answers and ill rate as always!

Comment: That shouldn't have mattered for a tinyint field

Comment: well it converted everything with quotes and executing again, haha.

Comment: appreciate teh edits guys!

Answer (score 0):

Explicitely call the mysql_error() function to see what happens. Example in https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php.